# how can i flag the read files to avoid reading them again in java?

Tags: java, file, csv

I have a code that reads CSV files and store their content into DB. The code runs periodically and it should only read the newly added files. I thought of adding a flag in the first line of each file after reading it, but this will require loading all the files one by one and check their first lines to decide which one should be read. 
Is there any better idea of doing it?

Comment: Just move the read file to `done` folder, new files remains in `new` folder, what is the problem?

Comment: @Rosdi Its a good idea if all the files are in your file system, but the problem is that i'm not sure if i will have permissions to create and maintain folders and files in the directories containing the files ( as they are not essentially in the same machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a Windows file-system (FAT, NTFS) there is a file attribute called "Archive" that is for this purpose. Any changes to the file cause it to be set, and you can clear it once you've added it to your DB.

For cross-platform purposes, the best option is to keep track of which files have been looked at (and optionally their last-modified dates) in the DB as well, then you can check while looking at the directory listing without having to open every file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would go for storing processed table names in DB for cross platform support.

Comment: @OrangeDog.. I found something called user defined attributes for files (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html#user) Do you think it is possible to use them to tag the read files? tried to find online if it is used for this purpose but could not find anything.

Comment: You could but, as it says, the file system may need re-mounting. That's quite a high-access requirement to place on anyone using your system though, and the attributes could be difficult to see/manage outside of your code - unlike the DB solution.

Answer (score 1):

an index file in the same directorywhich holds a list of the read files,

this way you only need to read that file to decide

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way: Store (the name of) all files you processed in a database table, and use that table to decide whether to process a file or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing much about your case, but can you ask the DB which files are stored, and just process the ones which aren't stored already? or you could store a list of processed files in memory for the next time you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

Delete readed files, there's no way to confusion

Answer (score 0):

Two solution from me:

1. Copy processed files to another directory.
2. Create a index file with a hash Code of files (cold be it name) where you will be able to check with file was processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to tamper those files. Thats a bad idea. 
Try to [set some property of the file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) to indicate that its processed. 
So u can differentiate it quickly the files that are to be read/processed.